# Supp of distribution- $\delta$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

how we can prouve that if $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $xT=0$ then $Supp T=\{0\}$?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if the support of $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Bbb R)$ is included in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ then
$$
\phi= x\,\frac{\phi}{x}, \quad\frac{\phi}{x}\in\mathcal{D}(\Bbb R).
$$
Now
$$
\langle T,\phi\rangle=\langle T,x\,\frac{\phi}{x}\rangle=\langle x\,T,\frac{\phi}{x}\rangle=0,
$$
that is, $\text{Supp}(T)\subset\{0\}$. If $T$ is not identically zero, this means that $\text{Supp}(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: hi, sorry, i don't understand. Can you explain me please why $Supp \delta=\{0\}$, and in some books i found that we haven't equality, just an inclusion, so i'm lost

Answer (score 1):

We can not guarantee that $supp(T)=\{0\}$, because a zero distribution $T=0$ also satisfies this equation, yet $supp(0) = \emptyset$.

In general case, if $f\in C^\infty$ and $T\in D'$ satisfy $fT=0$, then $supp T\subset \{x:\, f(x)=0\}$, this can be  easily show by definition, the Julián Aguirre's hint is a good start.

In your case the above result would yield $supp(T)\subset \{0\}$, and on top of that you can write $T$ explicitly: $T=c\delta_0$, $c\in \Bbb C$. The support of $\delta_0$ can be found by definition, too.